# Polygons on created surfaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to draw an arrow on a new surface so i can then rotate it, but when I draw it on the new surface I have created, it doesn't show up.

The icon shows up when it is put on the `game_display` surface but not when it is put onto the `player_icon` surface

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
grey = (175,175,175)

display_width = 1365
display_height = 700
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Person Shooter")
game_display.fill(black)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player_rotation = 0
player_icon_height = 15
player_icon_width = 15

def draw_map():
    player_icon = pygame.Surface((player_icon_width, player_icon_height))
    player_icon.fill(black)
    player_icon.set_colorkey(black)
    icon_position = [[int(player_location_x),int(player_location_y - (player_icon_height / 2))],[int(player_location_x - (player_icon_width / 2)),int(player_location_y + (player_icon_height / 2))],[int(player_location_x),int(player_location_y)],[int(player_location_x + (player_icon_width / 2)),int(player_location_y + (player_icon_height / 2))]]

    #This next line is the issue
    pygame.draw.polygon(player_icon, white, icon_position)
    blitted = game_display.blit(player_icon, [player_location_x - (player_icon_width / 2), player_location_y - (player_icon_height / 2)])
    player_icon_rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(player_icon, player_rotation)
    player_icon_rotated_rect = player_icon_rotated.get_rect()
    player_icon_rotated_rect.center = blitted.center
    game_display.blit(player_icon_rotated, player_icon_rotated_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()

draw_map()
```

It doesn't show up on the new surface but if I replaced the line with:

```
pygame.draw.polygon(game_display, white, icon_position)
```

then there isn't an issue

Comment: add screenes with pointers and refer to it... you lost me in the text. Also try debug via easy print-statements to see some values. This way you can check at various steps your output. Worst case use "import sys, print X, sys.stdout.flush(). Also make it a small working example... with `__if name__ == __main__:.. the usuall ;p)

Comment: I just don't understand how the same statement can be visible on some surfaces but not others. I don't really see how print statements can help in this situation. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates (`icon_position`) are out of bounds of the `player_icon` *Surface*. The coordinates must be relative to the *Surface* on which the polygon is drawn. The top left coordinate of a surface is always (0, 0), even if the surface is later `blit` at a different position later.

If the coordinates in `icon_position` are absolute window coordinates, you have to translate the coordinates relative to the `player_icon` *Surface*:

```py
rel_icon_position = []
for x, y in icon_position:
    rel_icon_position.append((x - blitted.x, y - blitted.y))
pygame.draw.polygon(player_icon, white, icon_position)
```

respectively

```py
rel_icon_position = [(x - blitted.x, y - blitted.y) for x, y in icon_position]
pygame.draw.polygon(player_icon, white, icon_position)
```